# Алгоритм поиска совпадающих цепочек в массивах

Tags: c#, алгоритм

Есть 2 массива байтов. Довольно большие. В обоих массивах присутствуют все байты (от 0 до 255).

Нужен алгоритм, который найдет совпадающие цепочки в массивах так, чтобы:

1. Первый массив был покрыт цепочками второго без пересечений.
2. Цепочек должно быть как можно меньше (то есть в приоритете самые длинные).

Это сложно объяснить, поэтому я покажу на примере.

Есть класс для сохранения информации о цепочке.

```
public class PartInfo
{
    public long Count { get; set; }

    public long Offset { get; set; }
}
```

есть 2 массива

```
var arr1 = new byte[]{2,3,5,2,7,3,9};

var arr2 = new byte[]{2,3,9,5,2,7,8,6,3,9};
```

В результате я ожидаю получить `PartInfo[]` с таким содержанием

```
Count | Offset
2 | 0
3 | 3
2 | 8
```

чтобы имея второй массив и вот эту сводную информацию я смог полностью восстановить первый.

**Время выполнения имеет значение**

Если чего непонятно, задавайте наводящие вопросы.

Comment: Хорошо, а в чем состоит ваш вопрос, что вы хотите видеть в ответе?

Comment: @Kromster В результате я хочу получить алгоритм. Хотя бы просто словами... но если он будет в виде функции на c# то вообще замечательно

Comment: Вы попробуйте нам объяснить как вы это думаете получить (мне до сих пор не понятно, и думаю не только мне), и бонусом вполне вероятно у вас уже будет готовы алгоритм.

Comment: @Сергей, не совсем вас понял. Если бы все было так просто, я бы не спрашивал. Самый топорный вариант - перебором. То есть я беру первый элемент первого массива, нахожу все позиции эквивалентного элемента во втором массиве. Далее беру следующий элемент, сравниваю его с элементами в найденных позициях + смещение... часть найденных ранее элементов при этом отбрасывается. Ну и так далее. Так находится цепочка. Потом беру элемент первого массива, который следует за этой цепочкой и ищу следующую цепочку. Но этот алгоритм работает ОЧЕНЬ долго!

Comment: А вообще что это будет? Зачем это всё?

Comment: Пожалуйста, добавляйте эти и другие подробности в тело вопроса.

Comment: @Сергей, бредовая идея. Я хочу попробовать освободить место на диске, создав архиватор, который не будет сжимать данные, а вместо этого будет использовать их повторно, например на основе системных файлов, которые не изменялись несколько лет с момента установки винды. Не уверен, что это даст хороший коэффициент сжатия, но попробовать все же стоит

Comment: Ну если не забираться в дебри математики (где эта задача не факт что имеет изящное решение) то окромя тупого перебора не вижу решений, но тут мы сталкиваемся с проблемами .NET. Управляемый код вряд ли даст провернуть это достаточно быстро, нужно unsafe   подключать - оно вам надо? Проще на Си такое ваять.

Comment: @iRumba. С приблизительным успехом, наверно, можно искать все эти последовательности в числе *e* или *π*. А во вторых, к примеру, послезавтра приезжает обновление Windows 11 какое-нибудь. Все-таки число *e* - надежней :)

Comment: _Цепочек должно быть как можно меньше (то есть в приоритете самые длинные)._ Это ДВА требования. И они несовместимы. Например, из двух вариантов 3+3 и 1+4+1 согласно _как можно меньше_ надо брать первый вариант, а согласно _в приоритете самые длинные_ - второй. PS. Алгоритму поиска наибольшей общей подпоследовательности в общем по барабану, текстовые данные или бинарные.

Comment: @Сергей, можно ускорить доступ к данным, если превратить массив в дерево... Правда, это потребует затрат оперативки.

Comment: @Akina, ну хорошо, пусть это будет средняя длина. На самом деле, имеет значение количество цепочек. 2 + 4 в данном случае будет аналогично 3 + 3.

Comment: Это из разряда мегаархиваторов которые могут очень круто сжимать в теории, но на практике требуют или бесконечного времени на работу, или бесконечной памяти, а то и того и другого)))

Comment: @Сергей, только в теории это сложно доказать. я вот не могу, поэтому и решил попытаться )

Comment: Напоминает архиватор Бабушкина)))

Comment: У вас в итоге таблица будет весить так же, сжатие будет в лучшем случае незначительное, в худшем  - даже наоборот больше чем исходник.

Comment: @Сергей, я думал об этом. В результате пришел к выводу, что бинарники, типа exe и dll имеют между собой много общего. Причем файлы, скомпилированные для .net между собой имеют еще больше сходств. То есть они имеют много схожих довольно длинных цепочек. Вот с картинками пока не разбирался, но уверен, что закономерности найдутся и там.

Answer (score 4):

Это проблема называется **LCS - "longest common subsequence"** (наибольшая общая подпоследовательность), используется в основном для поиска в строках. Самый быстрый алгоритм имеет сложность **O(n*m)**, где n - длина первой последовательности, m - длина второй последовательности. Для последовательностей в 1 Кб будем иметь более миллиона. операций, для файлов в 1 Мб число операций будет  уже триллион. Поэтому к файлам такое не применимо. В практике сжатия файлов используются словари с небольшими последовательностями битов.

Comment: Давайте не забывать про оптимизацию... Есть же всякие там деревья отрезков и тд

Comment: @iRumba дерево отрезков тут не поможет. Поверьте, до нас уже все придумали. Если хорошо с английским, можете почитать [тут](https://www.ics.uci.edu/~eppstein/161/960229.html) всякие варианты

Comment: Нет, эта задача хоть и похожа на LCS, но не эквивалентна ей.

Comment: деревья отрезков может и не помогут, но "и тд" вполне таки годятся. Например, создав из второго массива Dictionary<byte, List<long>>, где ключом является байт, а значением список всех его позиций в массиве, то скорость повышается

Comment: @iRumba это у вас повышается. Потому что у вас экспоненциальный перебор. Алгоритму основанному на динамическом программировании подобный трюк не поможет.